# How can I use a file to fill in missing information from another file using grep or awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep

I have two .tsv files, the first significantly longer than the other. The second files serves as an index of values associated with the marker present in the first. How can I fill the information from the second file into the first? I figured I could use grep or awk, but I am stumped as to how seeing as I am a beginner. Any help is appreciated!

file1

```
item_1
item_1
item_2
item_3
item_4
item_4
```

file2

```
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_2    13    1006323    1621313
item_3    11    1052636    1931233
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
```

wanted outcome

```
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_2    13    1006323    1621313
item_3    11    1052636    1931233
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
```

Comment: Are both files always sorted on the first field as shown in your example? If not please [edit] your example to show some lines out of order. Also please [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `join` utility performs an *equality join* on the specified files and writes the result to the standard output.

```
join file1.tsv file2.tsv
```

Comment: ...assuming both files are sorted on the key fields.

Comment: Specifically, you could do `join -1 1 -2 1 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Answer (score 0):

`awk`-based solution with

- no pre-sorting of files required
- `file-2` de-duped on line-wide basis

|

```
{m,n,g}awk 'NF = NR==FNR ? _*++__[$+_] : __[substr($+_, !_, match($+_, 
                 ".[ \t]"))]*+(__[$+_]++<NF)-(OFS="\n" $-_)' FS='^$' file1 file2

item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_2    13    1006323    1621313
item_3    11    1052636    1931233
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
```

it behaves somewhat similarly to `SQL` `SELECT` statement `INNER JOIN`s, but not necessarily identical ::

-- it returns the cartesian product of `non-de-duped file1` by `deduped-file2` (`"DD2"`), joined on `$1` of both, even if `$1` isn't unique within `DD2`

```
e.g. what "uniq -c" looked like after I randomized it, 
     plus altering value of last column in some of them :

           2 item_1 12 1002839 1231231
           2 item_1 12 1002839 1231232
           1 item_2 13 1006323 1621312
           1 item_2 13 1006323 1621313
           1 item_3 11 1052636 1931232
           1 item_3 11 1052636 1931233
           2 item_4 9 1024249 1631314
           2 item_4 9 1024249 1631315
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# print empty line if item does  not exist in file2.tsv
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}{$0=a[$1]}1' file2.tsv file1.tsv
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_2    13    1006323    1621313
item_3    11    1052636    1931233

item_4     9    1024249    1631315

item_4     9    1024249    1631315

# print only item if item does not exist in file2.tsv
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}{a[$1] ? $0=a[$1]: $0}1' file2.tsv file1.tsv
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_2    13    1006323    1621313
item_3    11    1052636    1931233
item_7
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
item_5
item_4     9    1024249    1631315

# skip line if item does not exist in file2.tsv
# $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}{if(a[$1]){$0=a[$1]}else{next}}1' file2.tsv file1.tsv
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_1    12    1002839    1231232
item_2    13    1006323    1621313
item_3    11    1052636    1931233
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
item_4     9    1024249    1631315
```